# Why is my xdebug not styled?

Tags: php, xdebug

So I have Xdebug enabled on my local version of PHP, and I'm wondering if anyone can give me an answer as to why the output isn't styled in the default way (with the orange background, table design).  I can see the stack trace and everything, but it's all just text, no html wrapper around the message.

Thanks if you have any advice to give!

BTW, this is in my php.ini file:

```
zend_extension="C:\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.show_local_vars=On
xdebug.dump.SERVER=*
xdebug.dump_globals=On
```

Comment: Not that this is a bad question, but have you checked the documentation? http://www.xdebug.org/docs/display

Comment: Well I've used it before in other machines, and for some reason the display was default and I didn't need to actively set the display settings.  I'm just wondering how this wasn't the case for my default settings on this machine, why it doesn't look the normal way off the bat.

Comment: Well, I understand. This is a slightly different question (title) though. Can you confirm that if you specifically set the correct settings, it works as you expect?

Comment: SO says I can't put an answer up for 24 hours, but I did find a solution -- I actually had html_errors turned off in the php.ini, so it's totally unrelated to xdebug.

Comment: Ok. Make sure and post the answer; it might help someone else.

Answer (score 32):

Make sure to have :

`html_errors = On`

set in `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

As I have answered in [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882037/xdebug-does-not-work-with-var-dump/65822692#65822692):

For Xdebug 3 you need to enable develop mode in your php.ini:

```
xdebug.mode= develop
```