# Xdebug does not work with var_dump()

Tags: php, xdebug, var-dump

I'm not sure why, but xdebug does not highlight var_dump(). But config seems to be fine. Have no idea why... Any suggestions?

This is my phpinfo(); http://pastebin.com/A45dqnWN

plus even xdebug_var_dump() doesn't highlight anything. It works, but look like normal var_dump().

Answer (score 22):

I found that option "xdebug.default_enable   Off     Off" in you php_info(). I also have noticed that in last versions of EasyPHP this option is turned off. So turn it on by setting this line in php.ini:

```
xdebug.default_enable=1
```

Next is just common operation which disables var_dump and other errors in HTML output completely (not your case, but maybe helpful for others):

```
html_errors = On
```

Comment: Thanks, just found out that html_errors bugged for so long cause they were disabled by default in my php.ini. Big tahnks to you, upvote

Comment: Also ensure `xdebug.overload_var_dump` is 1 or 2. If set to 0 it will not replace the default php `var_dump`

Answer (score 15):

For Xdebug 3 you need to enable develop mode in your php.ini:

```
xdebug.mode= develop
```

You can also use multiple modes at once as explained [here](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode).

#### The following values are accepted (for xdebug.mode):

- ###### off

  Nothing is enabled. Xdebug does no work besides checking whether functionality is enabled. Use this setting if you want close to 0 overhead.
- ###### develop

  Enables Development Helpers including the overloaded var_dump().
- ###### coverage

  Enables Code Coverage Analysis to generate code coverage reports, mainly in combination with PHPUnit.
- ###### debug

  Enables Step Debugging. This can be used to step through your code while it is running, and analyse values of variables.
- ###### gcstats

  Enables Garbage Collection Statistics to collect statistics about PHP's Garbage Collection Mechanism.
- ###### profile

  Enables Profiling, with which you can analyse performance bottlenecks with tools like KCacheGrind.
- ###### trace

  Enables the Function Trace feature, which allows you record every function call, including arguments, variable assignment, and return value that is made during a request to a file.

You can enable multiple modes at the same time by comma separating their identifiers as value to `xdebug.mode`: `xdebug.mode=develop,trace`.

Comment: This worked, but it wasn't stopping at the breakpoints. But you can combine multiple modes, so make sure to have at least `xdebug.mode=develop,debug`

Comment: Nice, thanks. This helped in getting pretty `var_dump` and breakpoint debugging.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by @Shadoweb for Xdebug v3 you want `debug` to allow stopping at breakpoints, and `develop` to format the `var_dump`

The following you'll likely want in php.ini therefore:

```
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
```

As an aside, I also needed `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` to replace the renamed `xdebug.xdebug.remote_enable=1` setting to get step debugging working in my IDE.

Comment: This should be the most upvoted answer b/c setting it to just `develop` will _stop_ breakpoints from working

Comment: Here is link from documentation saying that multiple values separated by commas is in fact officially supported - https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode

Answer (score 1):

For php 7.0.2 and xdebug 2.4.0

```
xdebug.default_enable=1
```

+

```
html_errors = On
```

Still does not colorize xdebug_var_dump() output.

but this patch fixes my issue. It applies to the xdebug.c and xdebug_var_dump() only. I think they made a mistake that xdebug_var_dump works only if it need to be overload function.

```
@@ -2191,11 +2191,6 @@
    int     i, len;
    char   *val;

-   if (!XG(overload_var_dump)) {
-       XG(orig_var_dump_func)(INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAM_PASSTHRU);
-       return;
-   }
-
    argc = ZEND_NUM_ARGS();

 #if PHP_VERSION_ID >= 70000
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn off xdebug.mode=debug in php.ini like

;xdebug.mode=debug

and restart Apache.